# How to solve webSockets protocol violation in android autobahn

Tags: android, websocket, publish-subscribe, autobahn

In my **android** **application** I want to use the autobahn library to use **websockets**. 
I have done server side code using spring. 
Simple socket is working when i am try pub sub then i get error.

My Code :-

```
final String wsuri = "ws://localhost:8080/ws";
try {
    mConnection.connect(wsuri, new Wamp.ConnectionHandler() 
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
            mConnection.subscribe("ws://localhost8080/ws/onetoone",
                MyEvent1.class, new Wamp.EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(String topicUri, Object event) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + event);
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost." + " " + reason);
    }
 });
} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

OutOut :-

> de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: created
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: created
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WampReader: created
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WampConnection: reader created and started
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: created
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WampWriter: created
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WampConnection: writer created and started
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: running
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: run() : WebSocketException 
>       (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException: RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated)
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: ended
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: opening handshake received
>       Status: Connected to ws://localhost:8080/Spring4WebSocket/add
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: fail connection [code = 4, reason = WebSockets protocol violation
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: quit
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: waiting for reader to finish
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: readr thread done
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: sending close message over socket
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: ended
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: waiting for writer to finish
>       de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: writer thread done
>       Connection lost. WebSockets protocol violation

I have pass ip address place on local host(my PC ip address).

Any have solution for how to solve  web Sockets protocol violation in android autobahn.

Please help for above problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated
```

implies that one or more of the reserved bits of a WebSocket frame which your WebSocket client received from your WebSocket server was not 0. If no WebSocket extension was negotiated (during the WebSocket [opening handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4)) as the error message claims, the reserved bits should be all zeros.

Check whether the endpoint of your WebSocket server is properly speaking the WebSocket protocol.